# Display with ST7036 controller -- rotate characters by 180 degrees?

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

I have a DOGM162 display (ST7036 controller). Am I blind, or is there really no way to turn the characters upside down?  Is there a way to program this device to rotate the characters 180 degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot turn characters upside down.  The datasheet for this display says it allows the user to create 8 custom characters, but the main character set is modeled in ROM and cannot be rotated 180 degrees.

Auf Deutsch:

Sie kann die Figuren nicht auf den Kopf stellen. Das Datenblatt für diese Anzeige sagt, dass es dem Benutzer erlaubt, 8 benutzerdefinierte Zeichen zu erstellen, aber der Hauptzeichensatz ist im ROM modelliert und kann nicht um 180 Grad gedreht werden.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just thought I've missed a special page about that in the datasheet - but well...

Comment: @STeVe if you found my answer helpful, please upvote or accept my answer so others can be helped also.